# Array function some does not narrow type, even when type predicate is used, alternative solution?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I would expect the array function some to narrow the type of dashArray when a type predicate and return statement is used.

- Is this something that the TypeScript compiler could reasonably do if it was smarter or am I wrong to expect such a thing?
- How can this come be rewritten to work as intended?

```
export function parseAsDashArray(str: string | null): number[] | null {
  if (!str) {
    return null;
  }

  const values = str.split(/[\s,]+/g);

  const dashArray = values.map((v) => parseAsPercentLength(v));

  if (dashArray.some(isNull)) {
    return null;
  }

  if (isOdd(dashArray.length)) {
    dashArray.concat(dashArray);
  }

  return dashArray;
}

export function isNull(val: any): val is null {
  return val === null;
}

export function parseAsPercentLength(val: string): number | null { ... }
```

EDIT: Here is a complete example that I tried pasting into the TypeScript playground.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

```
function parseAsDashArray(str: string | null): number[] | null {
    if (!str) {
      return null;
    };

    const values = str.split(/[\s,]+/g);

    const dashArray = values.map(parseAsPercentLength);

    if (dashArray.some(el => el == null)) {
      return null;
    }

    if (dashArray.length % 2 == 1) dashArray.concat(dashArray);

    return dashArray;
}

function parseAsPercentLength(val: string): number | null { 
  return Number.parseFloat(val)
}
```

> Type '(number | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'. Type
> 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'. Type 'null' is not
> assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: What exactly is your error? I pasted your code and it works perfectly fine

Comment: @Zer0: I added an edit. I used your code example.

Answer (score 0):

The TS compiler actually does that, from what I've got, you are trying to find null values and return null if given, I'd write that as following (without further context, you'd need to provide that). Also note: I just omitted the `return null` statements and shortened it to just return, as the TS compiler will ignore that anyways. Now it will return `undefined` but since `undefined == null`, it should not make a difference (except when using ===):

```
export function parseAsDashArray(str: string | null): number[] {
    if (!str) return;

    const values = str.split(/[\s,]+/g);

    const dashArray = values.map(parseAsPercentLength);

    if (dashArray.some(el => el == null)) return;

    if (dashArray.length % 2 == 1) dashArray.concat(dashArray);

    return dashArray;
}

export function parseAsPercentLength(val: string): number | null { ... }
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error when plugging the code into the TypeScript playground. See the edit in my OP.

Comment: Hm, quite interesting, it worked out fine for me on TS 3.8.3, I'll try something different @user1283776

Comment: I found some other solution, but this requires a second array, very weird, I wonder how that behaviour changed during the last TS versions, check [this](https://shorturl.at/nzFGK)

Comment: Thanks, I'm also curious. I did solve the problem, as you suggest, by using another array. I will post a solution in a few minutes for others to see.  But I don't know why the OP code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
export function parseAsDashArray(str: string | null): number[] | null {
  if (!str) {
    return null;
  }

  const values = str.split(/[\s,]+/g);

  const parsedArray = values.map((v) => parseAsPercentLength(v));
  const dashArray = parsedArray.filter(isValue);

  if (dashArray.length < parsedArray.length) {
    return null;
  }

  if (isOdd(dashArray.length)) {
    dashArray.concat(dashArray);
  }

  return dashArray;
}
```